# Who can access the different versions of edits?

Tags: discussion

Archiving edits is a wonderful feature. I was wondering whether high rep users can access them at all? because i learnt that SE allows high rep users see deleted pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this privilege is explained in the [Privileges - Edit Questions and Answers](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit) document (privilege enabled at 2000+ reputation).

Comment: Btw, Where is the link to Privileges actually? Maybe I missed it badly

Comment: @Thale - When viewing [main](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/), your username should appear at the top of the page toward the center. When you mouse-over your name, a dialog box should appear - the privileges link should appear at the top of this dialog next to your avatar icon. (I know, seems like a little bit of work to track it down)

Comment: yes yes yes! thanks you r polite!